# Connectedness of $\{(x,y)| x/y \in \mathbb Q\} \cup \{(x,0)|x\ne 0\}$

Tags: connectedness

I am trying to decide if the set $\{(x,y)| x/y \in \mathbb Q\} \cup \{(x,0)|x\ne 0\}$ is connected or disconnected. It is clearly not path-connected because it is impossible to get from line to the other without going through the origin, which is missing. I think it is also disconnected because it can be partitioned into two open sets by the line $y = \sqrt{2} x$. Is that right?

Comment: The lines $\{(x,y):\ x/y=\tan(\pi/6)\}$ and $\{(x,y):\ x/y=\tan(\pi/3)\}$ don't belong to the set and are two circles in the Riemann sphere that meet at the origin and at infinity. look at the open regions between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

---

Alternatively, the set does not contain the origin, hence we have a continuous  projection $(x,y)\mapsto \frac1{sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x,y)$, which has a countable (hence disconnected) subset of $S^1$ as image.